# How to save plot after the plot is zoomed

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Last few days I have been facing a problem in saving the matplotlib figure, three days before the code was working fine and saves the plot with changes made through the code, but now the changes (zoomed plot) is not saving rather it saves as it is when the plot is shown any changes made after does not reflects using the save command, don't know why?

```
    ax = pd.rolling_mean(dataToPlot_plot[startTime:endTime][['plotValue']],mar).plot(linestyle='-', linewidth=3,  markersize=9, color='#FECB00')
            ax.legend().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()#showing the plot
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)#setting the size of the plot, to fix in the PDF file
    fig.savefig('graph1.jpg')#saving the plot
```

even if I call a function, the new changed plot is not saved...

```
    def callmeto_plot()
            ax = pd.rolling_mean(dataToPlot_plot[startTime:endTime][['plotValue']],mar).plot(linestyle='-', linewidth=3,  markersize=9, color='#FECB00')
            ax.legend().set_visible(False)
            plt.show()#showing the plot
            fig = ax.get_figure()

            return fig

    fig = callmeto_plot()
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)
    fig.savefig('graph1.jpg')
```

How do I save the plot (zoomed one with changes) through code? 
 Note: I have noticed that the plot window appearance is also changed, 
 [1](http://i.imgur.com/9O4ScmX.png/) Plot window appearance before 
 [2](http://i.imgur.com/ogKJiPo.png/) Plot window appearance now 
 all the plot window configuration buttons are shifted from bottom to top, does this change affects only in the plot or affects the coding as well?. Please help me to fix this... 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell, how to save a plot after I zoom in the plot? the code was working two days before... Scenario 1: before, I plot the figure and close it the code saves the figure as .jpg and also saves the figure even with present changes for example figure is zoomed... Scenario 2: now when I plot the figure and close it saves the plot but when I zoom in and  close it, the figure wouldn't save the present selection I don't why, please give your suggestions on this... thanks

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell  [1] Old appearance plot window (i.imgur.com/9O4ScmX.png) [2] New appearance plot window (i.imgur.com/ogKJiPo.png). I am trying to know, does changes in the plot affects my previous code? How to save a plot after zoomed through the code, thanks for the help...

Comment: Please edit your question with those details

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell, does my edit make sense now?

Comment: What did you change about your system?

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell, same system windows 7 64 bit, same python 3.3, luckily I have python executables which I had convert three days before, the same code lies in both but old one saves the zoomed plot but the new one doesn't, I am finding hard to understand where could be the possible error... Thanks tcaswell again for your time and effort to give me suggestions...

Comment: Hi @tcaswell, still I haven't got any solutions, How to make this question in the priority list or I have to keep reposting same question until I get an optimal solution. Please advise, Thanx...

Comment: Do not re-post your question, that really annoys people.  The reason you have not gotten any good answers is that you have not provided enough information to sort out what the problem is.  Can you make a _complete_ and _minimal_ example which shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could move all the plot changing code above the `plt.show()` and then save the figure manually from the pop-up window. The right most icon at the bottom left saves the current figure as is currently displayed

Even better you could use `plt.axis([xStart, xFinish, yBottom, yTop])` or `ax.set_xlim(), ax.set_ylim`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you have mentioned I can save it manually but trying to do through the code so that its easy for every one. <br> [1] And also you mentioned "right most icon at the bottom" which i can't see now and all the icons have shifted to top. But three days before the plot was having the buttons at the bottom, I just want to know change in the plot affects the code as well? <br> [2] Old appearance plot window (http://i.imgur.com/9O4ScmX.png) <br> [3] New appearance plot window (http://i.imgur.com/ogKJiPo.png). <br> How to set it through the code, thanks for the help.

Comment: Any changes you perform to the window do not change the code. Set the limits of the X and Y axes and you will be good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @kameranis, but you've understood my problem incorrectly, I want to save the plot through the code. 1. Plot the graph. 2. Do changes on the graph. 3. Save the graph. That's all I am trying to make, please suggests me, thanks

Comment: Whatever you do change in the graph, does not change your code. Find what changes you want to do and write the right code to perform them automatically

Comment: Thanks @kameranis, my actual problem is that the code is not automatically performing, as mentioned before I want to save the plot automatically when the plot is zoomed (save the plot with present changes.), please suggest me the right directions.

Comment: I cannot think of an answer. I would suggest you find beforehand the changes you want to make and then write the code that does it. I cannot think of a way to do what you want.